# Use Multiple Filters in VS 2012 test explorer

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, test-explorer

I would like to filter on multiple criteria in Visual Studio 2012 test explorer search filter box.
I would like to get tests with trait "A" OR "B"
I have tried several versons of the below with no luck:
 Trait:"Integration"|"UnitTest" Trait:"Integration"|Trait:"UnitTest"

Searching for 1 trait alone works just fine.
I have loaded the latest VS 2012 CTP, that is why I can search by trait.

Comment: Looks like we would have to build a custom adapter?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vikramagrawal/archive/2012/07/23/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-rc-using-testcasefilter.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You are correct on this current limitation. I recommend you push your request via the [user voice channels](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio)  which are monitored for top user requests by our teams

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed now.  You can now filter tests by traits as well.  Traits can be categories as applied by attributes, or Owner, Priority, etc.  See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/09/how-to-manage-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-1-part-1-using-traits-in-the-unit-test-explorer.aspx) by the MS ALM team for details.